# vs2010 - shortcut for surrounding a String by double quotes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I used to work with a developer who, selects a text in aspx page and applies a keyboard shortcut to enclose it in double quotes.

Eg: runat=server. when i select server and press ctrl+somekey, it should be runat="server"

Could someone tell me what is the keyboard shortcut,  i tried googling a lot, but couldnt find one..

Currently we are overhauling a page, and need this badly...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you sure he didn't have a a custom macro defined?

Comment: not sure.. i lost his contact...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know this is a setting in Visual Studio which enables you to immediatelly place quotes when you type attribute and press equals sign or if you type a few letter and press CTRL+Space. This will autocomplete the attribute and place quotes. In order to enable the quotes click on `Tools` then `Options`. If it is not checked, check `Show all settings`. Expand `Text Editor`, then `HTML` and click on `Formatting`. On the right side enable **Insert attribute values quote when typing** and **Insert attribute value quotes when formatting**

Comment: Thanks. I had this option set in my VS. But due to the size of the old page(completely out of format), and the amount of data it is gonna format, the VS crashes once i press ctrl+d

Comment: Try formatting piece by piece. Apart from `Format whole document` you can also format selection (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F).

Comment: to my wonder... ctrl + f also crashes my VS., tat too only for this aspx file..!!!!

Comment: Try this, start a new project, add an aspx page, copy-paste from previous project to this new one. Try to format there and if it is successful copy-paste backwards. I cannot guarantee that this will work, but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: okay.. this also din work, looks like some problem with the page.
But found a quick work around. Created a small snippet to surround the selected text with " " and added it in the snippet manager(Javascript snippet manager) and boom here it works... 
ctrl K X "
thanks Huske, ur ideas made me to get an idea... :)

Comment: I'm glad that I helped even if it was just a small bit! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Format selection: ctrl+k, ctrl+f

I also have *Tools* > *Options* > *HTML* > *Formatting* > *Insert attribute value quotes when formatting* checked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this with the replace function

search : runat=server

replace: runat="server"

Comment: nice idea.. but only if i have to change runat=server, i wouldnt have posted this question... its a lot of attributes in the page...

Comment: that will replace only this example, I think OP needs solution that will work generally

Answer (score 0):

The developer may have been using a refactoring tool such as [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) or [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Have a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hf704tz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for how you may be able to do something similar without extra tools.