# Shortcut Double quote word when paste string or when i select the word Visual Studio 2019 && 2021

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, shortcut

I am searching through the internet to find a "shortcut" to paste text as a string (sorround by ") or quote a selected word:

[image: What command can i use to quote the selection?]

The most probably solution i found is that ,but it doesnt work for me:
[vs2010 - shortcut for surrounding a String by double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037384/vs2010-shortcut-for-surrounding-a-string-by-double-quotes)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that but it can be done using this extension

https://github.com/priyanshu92/SurroundSelection